# How can I check if attachments of a sent message is already synchronized to the server?

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I am developing an Outlook add-in for Mac in which I want to send the message to a CRM system after the user sent the message to the recipient(s).

The problem is that the attachments are not synchronized with the server yet at the time I fetch it using the REST Api.

The process I am currently trying to receive the message and send to the 3rd party server:

1. The user finishes editing the message and clicks 'Send' button in the Add-in
2. Add-in calls `Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()` and fetches the REST Api until the message appears on the server
3. Add-in inserts a hidden HTML tag in the body:

```
<a href="#syncid-${randomId}">&zwnj;</a>
```

4. Fetching email body using REST Api, until the **syncId** presents.
5. Send mail using `/v2.0/me/messages/<MAIL_ID>/send` REST Endpoint
6. Find and get sent message in the **SentItems** folder.
7. Get **Body** and **Attachments** of the mail using `/v2.0/me/mailfolders/sentitems/messages/<MAIL_ID>/attachments` Endpoint
8. Create EML and send it to a 3rd party service.

This process works until the 7th step.
The problem is the `.../attachments` call doesn't receive every attachment (inline and not inline) at the 7th step.
I have to wait until the attachments are synchronized and call the endpoint again.

Is there a possibility to check if the attachments are also synchronized with the server?

Its important to minimize the process time, so the User doesn't wait for long time. I also want to avoid using EWS if possible.

I tried few methods, but all of them have failed.

- I can't use `Office.context.mailbox.item.body.getAsync()` and `Office.context.mailbox.item.getAttachmentsAsync()` since it doesn't return the **ContentId**s, hence I can't pair them with the inline images or it would be very hard to do because the HTMLs are not consistent across multiple platforms.
- Extracting **ContentId**s from the mail body (which returned by the REST Api, not the `mailbox.item.body`) and wait until they appear in the server by polling the REST api every X second. The problem with this is that, if some attachments fail to synchronize or upload, then it waits indefinitely. Also can't check simple attachments this way.

Comment: Could you please provide us with more details on this?
1. What is the attachment size when you are facing this issue?
2. How many files are you attaching to the email?

Comment: It doesn't matter if I attach small or large files, the issue came up with both. Also the number of files doesn't matter. I always tested it with at least 3-4 small files.